# How to track parts through high-temperature oven and abrasive treatments?

Tags: materials, machining

I have been thinking of a problem and I would like to brainstorm about it with the community.

Scenario:
Machined parts going through termal treatment in an oven and further abrasive treatments. Temperatures of 900 celsius in the oven. Minimal space for marking. Laser do not work. RFID neither. 10mm marking space possible.

How can one track these parts? Any kind of paint? High temperature magnetic memory?

Comment: Why do the parts have to be tracked? Especially if they are all the same part ? How many parts per batch ?

Comment: A lot of items are tracked by batch or heat instead of individually. Could you add why you need to track them individually?

Comment: Is dot-peen marking allowable? Otherwise could you use a detachable tag? The tag could be laser or dot-peen marked and attached to the part through heat treat. Etc. it’s not perfect, but may work.

Comment: Could you specify why marking with a laser does not work?

Comment: ^I'd have thought because the abrasive treatment renders the laser marking illegible?

Comment: Oh, you're right, I only thought of the oven. But then again, OP explicitly mentioned that marking space is available, so I wonder if there's another catch for the laser

Comment: Can that marking space be lower that the finished surface so it does not get touched by the abrasive treatment?

Answer (score 1):

When they go into an oven they are on a particular sport on a rack. When they come out they will still be in the same spot.

That is your tracking method through the oven: track the rack the item is on and where it is on the rack. This also lets you collect data on which spots on the rack don't do as well as others.

However most bulk abrasive treatments for small machined parts is putting a bunch of parts into a container along with abrasive elements and then the container is agitated.

If the part is larger then you would be using additional machining to run sanding/grinding disks along it (or hand sanding). Again here you can track the position of the part instead of the part itself. Up until you can add the serial number.